# jQuery datepicker - dynamic selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to call all the input fields with id of the pattern aaa*.bbb where * is a number between 1 to 100.

My code is:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(PATTERN).datepicker({
                showOn: 'both'
            });
        });
```

My problems are:

1. If the id one of the input fields is simply "aaa.bbb" and I use `PATTERN = "#aaa\\.bbb"` then I can open the calendar, but no date is written into the input field when I click on a date... However if I omit the dot from the id and use `PATTERN = "#aaabbb"` I can select a date by the calendar. Hence I conclude that a dot in the id will not let me select a date by the calendar. How could it be??
2. Suppose I solve the dot issue from (1), I actually want to call only the relevant INPUT fields. (suppose again the id one of the input fields is simply "aaa.bbb") so I tried something like `PATTERN = "input[id$='\\.bbb']"`
   but it did not work (the calendar button would not appear at all. Even though it is explained here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ that in order to escape the dot character I "must escape the character with two backslashes: `\\.`"
   However when I try `PATTERN = "input[id$='\.bbb']"` the calendar button does appear, but again clicking on a date in the calendar would not cause the date to be written in the input field. Where do they say in the documentation that I have to use only one \ to escape the dot?
3. Suppose I solve the dot issues from (1) and (2), how do I write that the pattern is of the form aaa*.bbb ???

Thanks!

Comment: The double backslash escape method is only for use in `$('#id')` selectors. Using the attribute selector should not require it

Comment: Ok, and why is it that no date is being selected when I click on the calendar?

Comment: See my answer. I've also added a working demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery unfortunately does not have a "regex" selector. What you can do is find elements who's ID attributes start with "aaa" and end with ".bbb" then parse each for the number

```
$('[id^="aaa"][id$=".bbb"]').each(function() {
    var check = this.id.match(/aaa(\d+)\.bbb/);
    if (check != null && check[1] >= 1 && check[1] <= 100) {
        // ID matches required pattern
        $(this).datepicker({ showOn : 'both' });
    }
});
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/zjcN7/1/

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot! It works now and you've also answered all my other questions. Regarding the input field not accepting the value after clicking on the calendar, I figured out from your demo that it was due to me loading old versions of the jQuery files. I just updated the versions to the most recent ones as they appear in the demo and this problem was solved. I am just rather new to jQuery and did not know I was using an old version. Thanks again for your help!